# Extracting sentences using pandas with specific words

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a excel file with a text column. All I need to do is to extract the sentences from the text column for each row with specific words.

I have tried using defining a function.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

#################Reading in excel file#####################

str_df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\HP\Desktop\\context.xlsx")

################# Defining a function #####################

def sentence_finder(text,word):
    sentences=sent_tokenize(text)
    return [sent for sent in sentences if word in word_tokenize(sent)]
################# Finding Context ##########################
str_df['context'] = str_df['text'].apply(sentence_finder,args=('snakes',))

################# Output file #################################
str_df.to_excel("C:\\Users\\HP\Desktop\\context_result.xlsx")
```

But can someone please help me if I have to find the sentence with multiple specific words like `snakes`, `venomous`, `anaconda`. The sentence should have at least one word. I am not able to work around with `nltk.tokenize` with multiple words.

To be searched `words = ['snakes','venomous','anaconda']`

**Input Excel file :**

```
                    text
     1.  Snakes are venomous. Anaconda is venomous.
     2.  Anaconda lives in Amazon.Amazon is a big forest. It is venomous.
     3.  Snakes,snakes,snakes everywhere! Mummyyyyyyy!!!The least I expect is an    anaconda.Because it is venomous.
     4.  Python is dangerous too.
```

**Desired Output :**

Column called Context appended to the text column above. Context column should be like :

```
 1.  [Snakes are venomous.] [Anaconda is venomous.]
 2.  [Anaconda lives in Amazon.] [It is venomous.]
 3.  [Snakes,snakes,snakes everywhere!] [The least I expect is an    anaconda.Because it is venomous.]
 4.  NULL
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your `str_df`, and your desired output.

Comment: @JulienMarrec Edited. Thank you.

Comment: your third example with `because` has two sentences, which seems you want co-reference resolution, which is not easy. If you want sentence only extraction it is much easier (i.e. text delimited by !?.). Also, please show your current output, even if it is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how:

```
In [1]: df['text'].apply(lambda text: [sent for sent in sent_tokenize(text)
                                       if any(True for w in word_tokenize(sent) 
                                               if w.lower() in searched_words)])

0    [Snakes are venomous., Anaconda is venomous.]
1    [Anaconda lives in Amazon.Amazon is a big forest., It is venomous.]
2    [Snakes,snakes,snakes everywhere!, !The least I expect is an anaconda.Because it is venomous.]
3    []
Name: text, dtype: object
```

You see that there's a couple of issues, because the `sent_tokenizer` didn't do it's job properly because of the punctuation.

---

Update: handling plurals.

Here's an updated df:

```
text
Snakes are venomous. Anaconda is venomous.
Anaconda lives in Amazon. Amazon is a big forest. It is venomous.
Snakes,snakes,snakes everywhere! Mummyyyyyyy!!! The least I expect is an anaconda. Because it is venomous.
Python is dangerous too.
I have snakes


df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='0')
```

We can use a stemmer ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)), such as the [PorterStemmer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#module-nltk.stem.porter).

```
from nltk.stem.porter import *
stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer()
```

First, let's Stem and lowercase the searched words:

```
searched_words = ['snakes','Venomous','anacondas']
searched_words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in searched_words]
searched_words

> ['snake', 'venom', 'anaconda']
```

Now we can do revamp the above to include stemming as well:

```
print(df['text'].apply(lambda text: [sent for sent in sent_tokenize(text)
                           if any(True for w in word_tokenize(sent) 
                                     if stemmer.stem(w.lower()) in searched_words)]))

0    [Snakes are venomous., Anaconda is venomous.]
1    [Anaconda lives in Amazon., It is venomous.]
2    [Snakes,snakes,snakes everywhere!, The least I expect is an anaconda., Because it is venomous.]
3    []
4    [I have snakes]
Name: text, dtype: object
```

---

If you only want substring matching, make sure searched_words is singular, not plural.

```
 print(df['text'].apply(lambda text: [sent for sent in sent_tokenize(text)
                           if any([(w2.lower() in w.lower()) for w in word_tokenize(sent)
                                   for w2 in searched_words])
                                ])
 )
```

By the way, this is the point where I'd probably create a function with regular for loops, this lambda with list comprehensions is getting out of hands.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Yeah even I am encountering issues like "Snakes are venomous.Python too." I expect the output to be [Snakes are venomous.] but instead I am getting [Snakes are venomous.Python too.] since there isn't a space at the start of sentence.

Comment: Is there a way that i get sentences with 'snake' also even though I gave 'snakes' in words list. All I need is substring matching with words specified so that I don't loose any data to analyze the context.

Comment: Stemming is a possible solution but the problem statement doesn't just deal with structured data and to add i have a web crawler which fetches me the data so I am talking about large data (GB's), so it has data like 'snakesss' or words combined like 'snakesare' so when I search for snakes in text it should return sentence with 'snakesare' too!! Bottom line is i want substring matching to happen. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure it out, but I added a solution nonetheless

Comment: Thank you Julien I will look into it!

Comment: @Julien Marrec , Hi Julien, if i want to find individual words only for example only snake or only Anaconda, what would be a solution? in this example the function search for all words. I tried to apply a loop using words from a list but failed.